# replace extracted string content with an other on xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

Hello I want to replace some content of an extracted string (from a previous atrribute) with an other.
When I extract the attribute in this tag :

```
<UML:Package href='file.xml|638020a_1071071492996_282832_1598'>
```

with this xsl code :

```
<package href="{UML:StructuralFeature.type/UML:Classifier/@href}" />
```

I get ofcourse :

```
<package href='file.xml|638020a_1071071492996_282832_1598' />
```

but I want to get :

```
<package href='file.uml#638020a_1071071492996_282832_1598' />
```

any help ?

Comment: Your question is not well-defined. What is known about the extracted string? Will it always start with "file.xml|"? Or at least contain a "|" separator?

Comment: I will at leat contains ".xml" and a "|" separator like this ".xml|" I want to replace them with ".uml#"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming XSLT 1.0, I would do it this way:

```
<package>
    <xsl:attribute name="href">
        <xsl:variable name="href" select="UML:StructuralFeature.type/UML:Classifier/@href" />
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($href, '.xml|')"/>
        <xsl:text>.uml#</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-after($href, '.xml|')"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
</package>
```

You could rewrite this as attribute value template using the concat() function, if  you wanted.

Note: your XSLT selects `UML:StructuralFeature.type/UML:Classifier/@href` but your XML snippet shows an element named `UML:Package`. That doesn't fit.

Comment: No need for concat, you can have several `{}` placeholders in the same AVT.

Comment: @IanRoberts Right. Thanks for the added option. But neither allows using a variable - so both will be less efficient and certainly less readable than the verbose version.

Comment: True, you'd have to put the `xsl:variable` declaration before the `<package>` tag rather than inside it if you wanted to do this using an AVT.

Answer (score 0):

Use `fn:replace()`function :

```
<xsl:value-of select="fn:replace(/UML:StructuralFeature.type/UML:Classifier/@href, '.xml|', '.uml#')" />
```

(correct the xpath if needed, you have to use xslt 2.0 for this )

others string  functions [here](http://www.xqueryfunctions.com/xq/c0008.html) and [here](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_functions.asp)

Comment: do I have to define a name space or something because I didn't run for me here.
PS: I have xslt 2.0

Comment: the path to node is probably incorrect, but since we don't have the full xml source I can't help you more

Comment: @Iheb If you're using the `fn:` prefix, you must declare it first. But you don't have to use it.